# Comment deleted and reputation loss

Tags: discussion, comment, reputation, deletion

I made a comment in [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790744/if-0-9999-ldots-1-then-why-is-lim-n-to-infty-frac-tan89-n-text9) several minutes ago.

Very soon, before I had the time to edit, it got deleted and I also noticed that I lost about 40~50 reputation, without any notification. Nothing is shown in the reputation history.

The comment is the only thing that I have done in at least 12 hours, so I think the two events are related.

I have seen that moderators can delete comments, and flagged comments can get deleted, e.g. in [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/my-comment-disappeared). But I didn't expect that kind of reputation loss without notification.

Is it a normal situation that one can lose reputation without receiving any notification? And what is the logical basis of that, if there is such a rule?

Comment: These are unrelated, it's just a coincidence in timing. A question you had answered was deleted, and you lost 35 points from that (two upvotes + accept). If you check the "show removed posts" box on the "reputation" tab of your profile, you will get a link to the removed post shown in your reputation list.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, I didn't see the "show removed posts" checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perhaps your comment would make a reasonable answer....

Comment: If it were a good answer and a nice question which would have been a resource to the community you can flag the post for undeletion (and regain your rep)....This is also applicable if you have 0 upvotes (I have done so)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a temporal coincidence. Comment deletions have no reputation impact. (And your comment wasn't near bad enough to get you into trouble, it was just on the "delete" side of the "what to do when flagged" question.)

It just happened that in the same minute that your comment was deleted, also a question you had answered was deleted, and you lost the reputation from that answer.

Such reputation losses are only shown in your profile if the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the "reputation" tab is checked. If the deleted post is visible to the profile owner, the reputation entry is a link, otherwise it is just the plain text name of the post.